# Cannot read property 'fromWIF' of undefined error

Tags: bitcoinjs-lib

Im trying create and sign a raw transaction with bitcoinjs-lib.

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ecpair = require('ecpair');
const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
var keys    =new bitcoin.ecpair.fromWIF('cMvPQZiG5mLARSjxbBwMxKwzhTHaxgpTsXB6ymx7SGAeYUqF8HAT', bitcoin.networks.testnet);
```

this is my code and i get error "Cannot read property 'fromWIF' of undefined error" message.
i think i am making a mistake while adding the libraries.
bitcoinjs-lib version is 6 and using nodejs.
thank you.

Comment: Does it work if you switch the import order? First import the bitcoinjs-lib, and the ecpair-lib afterwards

Comment: yes, This is how it should be imported: const { ECPair } = require('ecpair');